# New to C# command prompts and trying to understand this code

Tags: c#, variables

```
float originalFahrenheit;
float Kel;
Console.Write("Enter temperature (Fahrenheit): "); 
originalFahrenheit = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

With the float parse I was wondering if it was already a float to begin with why it needed to parse to float. Is this because anything the user inputs is string? And therefore it had to be parse?
Sorry if it's a bit pointless just having trouble understanding?

Comment: A method in C# always returns one type of object. It can return a string, or a float, but it can't return both. (It can however return Object, which could be either String or Float). Console.ReadLine(), for example, returns a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're quite right - the user's input from `Console.ReadLine()` is always a string.  `float.Parse()` turns that string into a `float` for you.

Answer (score 2):

It comes in as a `String` from the `Console.ReadLine()` and therefore needs to be parsed.

that code is slightly dangerous though as there is no surety that the user will enter something in the correct format. This is why there is a `float.TryParse()` that has an out parameter and returns a `bool` depicting if the parsing was successful or not.

```
float myFloat;
if (float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out myFloat))
{
   //Do something with your float here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [`Console.ReadLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method returns `string` always.

```
Return Value
Type: System.String
The next line of characters from the input stream, or null if no more lines are available.
```

Also you can be sure your `string` can be parse to `float` or not with using [`Single.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26sxas5t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
float originalFahrenheit;
float Kel;
Console.Write("Enter temperature (Fahrenheit): "); 
string str = Console.ReadLine();

if (Single.TryParse(str, NumberStyles.Float, out originalFahrenheit))
{
  //Successful parsing..
}
```